# Broken pipe with C3P0, JPA 2.0 and Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have a serious problem with broken pipe, I've tried everything and could not solve ... Below is the error that occurs after 8 hours without using the software ...

Error from tomcat

```java
Dec 29, 2014 11:44:19 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
SEVERE: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:72)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:277)
    at br.com.clikyapp1.modelo.UsuarioDAO.login(UsuarioDAO.java:27)
    at br.com.clikyapp1.controle.ControleLogin.efetuarLogin(ControleLogin.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2062)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:906)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2550)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2536)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2366)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2361)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:495)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:198)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1194)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:268)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 54,542,190 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 54,542,190 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1036)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3661)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2417)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2030)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3643)
    ... 59 more
```

My persistence.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="clikyapp1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <!--<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> -->
        <!--<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider> -->

        <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.Cultura</class>
        <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.Cidade</class>
        <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.Estado</class>
        <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.TipoDespesa</class>
        <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.Safra</class>
        <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.TipoContrato</class>
        <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.Area</class>
        <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.Armazem</class>
        <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.Conta</class>
        <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.Parceiro</class>
        <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.Usuario</class>
        <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.Fixacao</class>
        <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.Venda</class>
        <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.Modalidade</class>
        <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.LocalEntrega</class>
        <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.VinculoContrato</class>
        <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.OcorrenciaContrato</class>
        <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.LocalEntregaContrato</class>
        <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.Contrato</class>
        <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.Indexador</class>
        <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.CessaoCreditoContrato</class>
        <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.PenhorContrato</class>
        <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.CessaoCreditoVenda</class>
        <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.PenhorVenda</class>
        <class>br.com.clikyapp1.bean.DadosPagamentoContrato</class>
        <properties>
            <!-- Configuring JDBC properties -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="******" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/clikyapp1" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

            <!-- Hibernate properties -->
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <!--<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />-->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults"
                value="false" />

            <!-- Configuring Connection Pool -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class"
                value="org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="3" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="100" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout"
                value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="100" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1"/>  
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My EntityManagerUtil.java

```java
package br.com.clikyapp1.jpa;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

    public class EntityManagerUtil {

        private static EntityManager entityManager = null;
        private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = null;

        public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
            if(entityManagerFactory == null) {
                entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("clikyapp1");
            }

            if(entityManager == null) {
                entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
            }

            return entityManager;
        }
    }
```

any idea? thanks...

Comment: likely firewall or the likes that kicked out an inactive network connection. You need to configure your connection pool (c3po or dbcp) to regularly check connections. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075577/hibernate-c3p0-server-crashes-after-mysql-timeout?rq=1

Comment: I've set up a pool with c3p0... but don't work....

Comment: please elaborate a bit on the "don't work" part.